# How to vertically stretch two Views that are in a column formation - React Native Flex?

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox

I have this view, where there are two Views in a column:

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange'}}>
                <Text>Test</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                <Text>Test2</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
```

This is my Styles:

```
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    height: 80,
    margin: 8,
},
content: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    flexDirection: 'column',
},
```

Here is a [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydBU8.jpg) of what it looks with the above code.

How can I get the orange and yellow View to expand vertically equally, without manually defining the height for each of them?

The Text inside should be centered, but left-aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to each cell to make them expand and add `justifyContent: 'center'` to make the text vertically centered. Like this:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'orange', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Test2</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: What if I want the top View to be 75%, and the bottom View to be 25%?

Comment: Use flex: 3 and flex:1
More info about flex: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/